# Computer answers in poetry

Tags: story-identification, poetry

I'm looking for a short story my dad believes he read in Analog sometime in the early/mid 70's.

The story involved a computer that when posed questions about military/space travel etc., answers with poetry. He said there's an older woman who was somehow responsible for this.

I would really appreciate any answers to what this story might be, or who the author was! My dad thought it was written by Isaac Asimov, but we looked for it under his works and couldn't find it.

Can anyone identify this story?

Comment: Does it give answers in [haiku](http://www.snopes.com/computer/internet/haiku.asp) ?

Comment: Hmmm, my dad didn't mention haiku, but it sounds possible! Does it sound familiar?

Comment: Hmm, I would have said [EPICAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPICAC_%28short_story%29) but some of the details you mention don't match well with that story.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old one, and the OP is unlikely to see the answer.

[The answer is](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51187) *Answer Affirmative or Negative* by Barbara Paul.  (Analog 1972)

A computer named WOMAK starts answering any question with a line of poetry. When asked about a rocket launch's chance of success, it replies "out of this nettle, danger, we pluck this flower, safety" (a quote from Shakespeare). A politician asks for his chances of election, and WOMAK says "get thee to a nunnery."

The protagonist traces one of WOMAK's programmers, miss Whatsit, who likes poetry.

At the end, WOMAK give his regards to cousin Dooley. Protagonist reflects that Miss Whatsit also [likes baseball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dooley_Womack).

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a stretch, but I wonder if you're thinking of the story [“Light Verse”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46101) by Asimov. I read it in [*Buy Jupiter*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?25249) but it has also been anthologised elsewhere. It wasn't pubished in *Analog*.

The old woman is the owner of a robot, Max, that was defective when delivered to her:

> The very last person anyone would expect to be a murderer was Mrs. Avis Lardner. Widow of the great astronaut-martyr, she was a philanthropist, an art collector, a hostess extraordinary, and, everyone agreed, an artistic genius. But above all, she was the gentlest and kindest human being one could imagine.

She is famous for her light sculptures. The link to poetry is in the title and the line in the story:

> “I wouldn't call it 'poetry in light.' That's far too kind. At most, I would say it was mere 'light verse.'“ And everyone smiled at her gentle wit.

The robot creates the light sculptures. Although the manufacturing fault means it isn't much use for everyday tasks, it somehow endowed the robot with the creative genius to make the sculptures. I won't give away the ending in case you want to reread it.

The story doesn't match the description of the robot replying to questions about military issues or space travel, but it matches in enough areas that I wonder if it's being conflated with another story in your Dad's memory.

Comment: But you _did_ give away the ending, in the first sentence of the first quotation!